# Vertica copy query and Null Value

Tags: vertica

I have a table in vertica Database, its column CON_BRWR is Varchar(100) Not Null.

I am applying encryption on this column. If this column gets empty string, that row should be rejected but due to encryption it encrypts the empty string and Null also.

To overcome this problem i tried this solution

```
COPY myschema.CON_BIZ ( __tempCON_BRWR FILLER VARCHAR(100),
CON_BRWR as Case WHEN __tempCON_BRWR = '' THEN NULL ELSE AESEncrypt(__tempCON_BRWR,'abcdefg') end 
) FROM STDIN ENCLOSED BY '"' delimiter ',' ENFORCELENGTH SKIP 1 rejected data as table ErrorTable no commit;
```

that if **__tempCON_BRWR** filler gets empty string it should not encrypt value but in any case

> it is going in else condition

I am stuck, any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: you can't do it, but I have some workarounds if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

> it is going in else condition

Your syntax a little problematic for Vertica parser, see example for right syntax.

**NOTE:**
But it will not solve your main problem -> reject row.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.haroon
(
    id int,
    raw varchar(100),
    encrypted varchar(100)
);
```

**Populate table with `COPY FROM STDIN` statement:**

(most important part, take a look on `CASE` syntax and on definition of `NULL` in copy)

```
copy haroon(
    id,
    rawdata filler varchar(100),
    raw as rawdata,
    encrypted as case rawdata = '' or rawdata is NULL
        when TRUE then NULL
         else AESEncrypt(rawdata, 'secret')
    end)
from stdin ENCLOSED BY '"' NULL as '' delimiter ',' direct abort on error;

daniel=> \e
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1,""
>> 2,
>> 3,foo
>> \.
```

- `{column} as case {filler} = '' or {filler} is NULL when TRUE then NULL else AESEncrypt({filler}, {password})`
- `COPY ... NULL AS ''`

**Test:**

```
daniel=> select id, raw, encrypted::varchar(3), encrypted is NULL from haroon ;
 id | raw | encrypted | ?column?
----+-----+-----------+----------
  1 |     |           | t
  2 |     |           | t
  3 | foo | ��        | f
(3 rows)
```

You can see that 2 first rows (id = [1,2]) contains `NULL` in encrypted column, data loaded without any issues.